# New file pushed to remote branch not in solution explorer

Tags: git

I am new to git. I made changes on a separate computer by adding a file, I pushed the changes to a remote branch and then tried to get those changes/files on a separate computer. I pulled from my remote branch and can see the commit which added the file on the other computer, and the file itself in the branch history. However, that file is not showing up in my solution explorer. It says that my repository is up to date and there are no changes to pull as well. I am confused why the file I pushed from the first machine does not show in my solution explorer?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you pulled from the correct branch?

Comment: I think so? In the branch history it shows my commit of "added test function" and I pulled that branch. But then in my git changes it says "Repository is already up to date. No changes to pull." and then in my solution explorer I am missing that new file (and the folder it is in)

Comment: Do you have the correct commit checked out? Have you tried refreshing or reopening your "solution explorer" (whatever that is)?

Comment: I am not sure. I tried to check out that commit and none of the files became present in the solution explorer (Sorry for reference the solution explorer is just the window where my files show up in the Visual Studio IDE). And for context I have just been using the tools in Visual Studio, not the command line.

Comment: @tothemax would you please edit your post by inserting the steps you took from the beginning? So we can see if there was something you missed or did wrong!

Comment: Honestly, not sure what I did but they are present now?? Thanks @Yoji